# Issue Linking DB Table to GISRegions in Anylogic/ Spawning Agents to the GISRegions

Tags: java, gis, anylogic, agent, agent-based-modeling

I am working in AnyLogic and am quite new. Description: of 'Tract' Country>State>County>City>Tract. I have census tract data of the different districts of a city. In this data each row is one "tract" which has a population associated with it. I have a shape file of the tracts within the city. That is then added to the GIS map and converted from the shape file to a space markup. That created GISRegions that represent each tract within the city. I am now trying to spawn the population amount of people agents on the GISRegion/tract associated with its population. So I am trying to link the GISRegions/tract to their respected row so that the population can be created and be different for each GISRegion/tract. I have created an agent that takes in all of the data from an excel file and makes it into parameters on the Person(Agent) home page. This I believe to be the problem as I can not convert the 'ANYLOGIC' name column from a string to a GISRegion. This name column is a string version of the names of the tracts. The GISRegions have the same names as the data that populates 'ANYLOGICNAME'. Example of the naming convention EX: _24_12. If i could convert the ANYLOGIC name column from a string to a GISRegion i beleive this would link the two and relate the GISRegion/tract to its respected row so that the population can be grabbed and used to produce agents at this GISRegion/tract. I am not the best at AnyLogic but am trying to learn and progress. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to put put the GISRegions into a Collection and create a function to make that link but to no avail. What I expect to do is randomly generate in each tract/GISRegion the population size of people Agents

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.